# "Giving the end" of sellotape

Tags: expressions, phrases

Normally we would have to find it by rolling the tape and touching the entire perimeter to see the "undulation" and then we would have to strip the tape from its holder. How do I ask someone to give me the end of the sellotape strip?

Comment: By the way, "sellotape" is a very British English expression.  In the US, we would probably just say "tape" or maybe "Scotch tape" after the best-known brand.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might want to say something like:

> Can you find the end of this roll of sellotape for me please?

### OR

> I can't find the end of this roll of sellotape! Can you do it?

### OR

> I can't find the end of this roll of sellotape! Can you find it for me?

Comment: "End of this roll of sellotape" : I am finding it a bit difficult, could I just simply say: "end of this sellotape roll" instead?

Comment: Yes that would make sense too, but it is more commonly referred to as a "roll of sellotape".